# How can I create a buffer of uninitialized objects in C++?

Tags: c++

Suppose I want to create a memory pool so that I can control the memory locality of a large number of small, polymorphism-free objects. Naively I would do `std::array<T, MAX_SIZE>`, or even just `T[MAX_SIZE]` and then use placement new. However, both of these insist on initializing all of the objects, which in turn:

- Forces the objects to have a default constructor
- Could hurt my program's startup time if these objects are expensive
- Could open a massive can of static initialization worms if my buffer is static

So what I really want is the buffer contents to stay *uninitialized* until placement new is called on each slot. The solution I've found is to declare the buffer as `std::array<char, MAX_SIZE*sizeof(T)>` instead, but this throws away type safety completely and is super ugly. Is there a better way?

Also, why is C++ like this? I find it super bizarre that C++ is so pedantic about uninitialized objects while it cheerfully destroys my object invariants via object slicing, and has no problem leaving my enums uninitialized...

Comment: `std::vector` would work well for this.  After you create the vector, you can call `reserve` to allocate enough space for the objects you want, but none will be created until you actually `push`/`emplace` the objects into the vector.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_value_construct and related functions?

Comment: Based on these comments, `std::vector` is looking more and more attractive. The main reason I've avoided it so far is because I'd need to use both emplace_back and placement new, which makes the allocation algorithm uglier.

Comment: You don't need to use `placement-new` with `vector` at all. Let `emplace_back()` construct the object for you.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot use `std::array<char, MAX_SIZE*sizeof(T)>` as a backing storage for arbitrary types as there is no guarantee that the array will be well-aligned to `alignof(T)`.

The idiomatic way to allocate uninitialized space is to use `std::aligned_storage_t`. For your case, it would be `std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T) * MAX_SIZE, alignof(T)>`. Then you can placement new (or use the standard functions related to uninitialized memory) at the correct offsets into this array without causing undefined behavior.

If you don't care about heap allocations, you should use `std::vector<T>` as NathanOliver suggests in the comments.

Comment: I removed the aligned storage trap by adding a `_t`; I have made that mistake myself.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, thanks! It looks like I'll never learn this :)

Comment: "*For your case, it would be `std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T) * MAX_SIZE, alignof(T)>`*" - the correct way to use `std::aligned_storage_t` for an array is to use it as the array's element type, not use it to define the whole array, eg: `std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> array[MAX_SIZE];` See the [example on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage)

Answer (score 1):

Since you will ever only store a single type in your pool, instead of `std::aligned_storage_t`, you could also use a union with a single member:

```
template <class T>
union uninit_holder {
  uninit_holder() {} // Intentionally empty
  ~uninit_holder() {} // Ditto
  T val;
};
```

And use a `std::array` with it:

```
std::array<uninit_holder<T>, MAX_SIZE> arr;
```

When you want to create one, you can placement new into the object and call `std::destroy_at` to destroy one when you no longer need it.

(Since this answer proposes a completely different approach, I added another answer instead of editing my original one.)

Comment: That's a cool trick! I'm still leaning towards `std::aligned_storage_t` because it looks like it lets me specify stricter alignments than the object itself cares about (e.g. to cache lines)

Comment: Side question: Why would I use `std::destroy_at` instead of just `~T`?

Comment: I think `std::destroy_at` is more clear to read, and not everyone knows you can call destructors like that.